# вылетает приложенния (Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Не понимаю что делаю не так

Вот ошибки

```
2021-01-25 19:39:27.366 28218-28218/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.weather, PID: 28218
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.weather.POJO.Main com.example.weather.POJO.Example.getMain()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.weather.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:109)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$hVGjmafRi6VitDIrPNdoFizVAdk.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6671)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
2021-01-25 19:39:27.384 28218-28218/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28218 SIG: 9
```

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.weather.POJO.Example;
import com.example.weather.POJO.Main;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager;

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    static double latitude;

    private double longtitude;

    TextView textView;


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        if(!checkPermission()){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            getLocation();
        }
    }


    private boolean checkPermission(){
        int FineLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int CoarseLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(FineLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && CoarseLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        return false;
            } else{
                return true;
            }
        } else{
            return true;
        }

    }

    private void getWeather(){
        final String API = "0fcdeed0b44f8572a682c8837f51a541";
        final String CELSIUS = "metric";
        

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        CurrentWeather currentWeather = retrofit.create(CurrentWeather.class);

        Call<Example> exampleCall = currentWeather.weather(latitude, longtitude, API);
        exampleCall.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                Example myData = response.body();
                Main main = myData.getMain();
                double temp = main.getTemp();

                textView.setText(String.valueOf(temp));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLocation(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locationListener.onLocationChanged(location);

        getWeather();

    }



    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            if(location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longtitude = location.getLongitude();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("GPS disable!");
            builder.setMessage("Do you want enable GPS?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //start settings window when user can enable GPS
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //close AlertDialog
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog enableGps = builder.create();
            enableGps.show();
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            finish();
        } else {

        }
    }
    
}
```

**CurrentWeather**

```
package com.example.weather;

import com.example.weather.POJO.Example;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public interface CurrentWeather {

    @GET("wearther?")
    Call<Example> weather(@Query("lat=") double latitude,
                          @Query("&lon=") double longtitude,
                          @Query("&appid=") String api);
}
```

**Example**

```
package com.example.weather.POJO;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;
    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    public Main main;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    public String name;

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }

    public Main getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
package com.example.weather.POJO;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Main {

    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    public double temp;
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    @Expose
    private double feelsLike;
    @SerializedName("temp_min")
    @Expose
    private double tempMin;
    @SerializedName("temp_max")
    @Expose
    private double tempMax;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    @Expose
    private int pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private int humidity;
    @SerializedName("sea_level")
    @Expose
    private int seaLevel;
    @SerializedName("grnd_level")
    @Expose
    private int grndLevel;

    public double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public double getFeelsLike() {
        return feelsLike;
    }

    public void setFeelsLike(double feelsLike) {
        this.feelsLike = feelsLike;
    }

    public double getTempMin() {
        return tempMin;
    }

    public void setTempMin(double tempMin) {
        this.tempMin = tempMin;
    }

    public double getTempMax() {
        return tempMax;
    }

    public void setTempMax(double tempMax) {
        this.tempMax = tempMax;
    }

    public int getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    public void setPressure(int pressure) {
        this.pressure = pressure;
    }

    public int getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(int humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    public int getSeaLevel() {
        return seaLevel;
    }

    public void setSeaLevel(int seaLevel) {
        this.seaLevel = seaLevel;
    }

    public int getGrndLevel() {
        return grndLevel;
    }

    public void setGrndLevel(int grndLevel) {
        this.grndLevel = grndLevel;
    }

}
```

**Weather**

```
package com.example.weather.POJO;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Weather {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("main")
    @Expose
    private String main;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("icon")
    @Expose
    private String icon;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(String main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

}
```

Comment: 99% на то, что вы неправильно парсите JSON. 1% - что-то не то в запросе. Покажите JSON

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно в логи - если увидите `java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to * not permitted`, то пробуйте так: `.baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")` (http**s**), либо изучайте: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config. Тут статья попроще, наверное: https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6

Comment: Плюс пара замечаний: `@Query("&lon=")` - здесь лишние символы, должно быть только имя параметра. И `getWeather()` вызывается до того как сработает `LocationListener` - первый запрос пойдёт по координатам `0, 0`

Comment: ```@Query``` использовал лишние символы уже от безысходности. Проблема была в ```@GET``` вместо ```@GET("weather")``` я написал ```@GET("wearther")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Query использовал лишние символы уже от безысходности. Проблема была в @GET вместо @GET("weather") я написал @GET("wearther")